# Tableau Multiple Value Filter delay update

Tags: tableau-api

I have a large tableau dashboard including a number of charts and Summary views and attached to these I have a number of multiple value text filters all non calculated fields.

I am trying to improve the update speed and wonder if there is a method of setting these specific filters so that the views update after the full selection is made and the user has toggled off the filter option. Currently the views update each time a option is selected from the tickbox list.

Does anyone know a method of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Simply click the drop down arrow on the filter menu > go to “customize”, then click “show apply button”.

Answer (score 0):

Abhishek Boorugu answer should work for you Dan. If you want data to be filtered before the dashboard is loaded, try Context Filters. More explanation on the same can be found [here](https://community.tableau.com/thread/202496)

Comment: Thanks reinstate Monica. This looks to be a useful reference.

Comment: If you are working with very heavy datasets, it does help.